# Is TeamFoundation Server 2012 compatible with Windows Server 2019

Tags: tfs

I would like to upgrade my team foundation server OS to windows server 2019 due to existing OS EOL soon. Kindly advise whether TFS 2012 compatible with Windows Server 2019

Answer (score 0):

TFS 2012 was EOL in January 2018. If you're updating your Operating System due to EOL support, then I would encourage you to upgrade TFS as well, given the version you have is EOL.

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/get-started?view=azure-devops-2020&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops) for upgrade guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/requirements?view=azure-devops-2020#server-operating-systems) you can refer to:

[image]